# How to fix "undefined reference to `YAML::operator<<(std::ostream&, YAML::Node const&)'" in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, libs

I did a project in manjaro, then decided to switch to ubuntu and everything flew to hell. I've installed libpoco-dev, libtinyxml2-dev and libyaml-cpp-dev

my cmakelist file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(auchan_handler_microservice)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wall -Werror")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set(LIB_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/extern")

add_executable(auchan_handler_microservice main.cc)
include_directories(src)
add_subdirectory(src)

option(PACKAGE_TESTS "Build the tests" ON)
if (PACKAGE_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif ()

find_package(Poco REQUIRED Foundation Net Util DataMySQL)

target_link_libraries(auchan_handler_microservice src)
target_link_libraries(auchan_handler_microservice yaml-cpp tinyxml2)
target_link_libraries(auchan_handler_microservice Poco::Net Poco::Util Poco::DataMySQL)
```

error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `Application::main(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)':
/home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:29: undefined reference to `YAML::LoadFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:31: undefined reference to `YAML::operator<<(std::ostream&, YAML::Node const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:38: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams::HTTPServerParams()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:38: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::ServerSocket::ServerSocket(unsigned short, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:38: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPServer::HTTPServer(Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory> >, Poco::Net::ServerSocket const&, Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:38: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::ServerSocket::~ServerSocket()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:39: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::TCPServer::start()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:41: undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::waitForTerminationRequest()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:38: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPServer::~HTTPServer()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:38: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::ServerSocket::~ServerSocket()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.cc:38: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPServer::~HTTPServer()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::host() const':
/usr/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:81: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPAddress(void const*, unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::host() const':
/usr/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:143: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::IPAddress::IPAddress(void const*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::Exception::Exception(YAML::Mark const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/exceptions.h:122: undefined reference to `vtable for YAML::Exception'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::RepresentationException::RepresentationException(YAML::Mark const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/exceptions.h:155: undefined reference to `vtable for YAML::RepresentationException'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::InvalidNode::InvalidNode()':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/exceptions.h:198: undefined reference to `vtable for YAML::InvalidNode'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::BadSubscript::BadSubscript()':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/exceptions.h:228: undefined reference to `vtable for YAML::BadSubscript'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::detail::memory_holder::create_node()':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/memory.h:37: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::memory::create_node()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::detail::node_ref::mark_defined()':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:30: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::detail::node_ref::set_null()':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:36: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::node_data::set_null()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::detail::node_ref::set_scalar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/node_ref.h:37: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::node_data::set_scalar(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::Node::EnsureNodeExists() const':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:54: undefined reference to `YAML::InvalidNode::~InvalidNode()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:54: undefined reference to `typeinfo for YAML::InvalidNode'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::Node::Type() const':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:78: undefined reference to `YAML::InvalidNode::~InvalidNode()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:78: undefined reference to `typeinfo for YAML::InvalidNode'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::Node::Scalar[abi:cxx11]() const':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:158: undefined reference to `YAML::InvalidNode::~InvalidNode()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:158: undefined reference to `typeinfo for YAML::InvalidNode'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:159: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::node_data::empty_scalar[abi:cxx11]'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `void YAML::Node::Assign<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:222: undefined reference to `YAML::InvalidNode::~InvalidNode()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:222: undefined reference to `typeinfo for YAML::InvalidNode'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `HandlerFactory::HandlerFactory()':
/home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler_factory/handler_factory.h:9: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::Node YAML::Node::operator[]<char [5]>(char const (&) [5])':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:388: undefined reference to `YAML::InvalidNode::~InvalidNode()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:388: undefined reference to `typeinfo for YAML::InvalidNode'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::detail::node& YAML::detail::node_data::get<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>)':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:112: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::node_data::convert_to_map(std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:115: undefined reference to `YAML::BadSubscript::~BadSubscript()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:115: undefined reference to `typeinfo for YAML::BadSubscript'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:126: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::node_data::insert_map_pair(YAML::detail::node&, YAML::detail::node&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `YAML::detail::node& YAML::detail::node_data::convert_to_node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>)':
/usr/include/yaml-cpp/node/detail/impl.h:179: undefined reference to `YAML::detail::memory_holder::merge(YAML::detail::memory_holder&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11Application[_ZTV11Application]+0x20): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::name() const'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11Application[_ZTV11Application]+0x28): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::initialize(Poco::Util::Application&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11Application[_ZTV11Application]+0x30): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::uninitialize()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11Application[_ZTV11Application]+0x38): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::reinitialize(Poco::Util::Application&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11Application[_ZTV11Application]+0x40): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::defineOptions(Poco::Util::OptionSet&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11Application[_ZTV11Application]+0x48): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::run()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTV11Application[_ZTV11Application]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Util::Application::handleOption(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `Application::~Application()':
/home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/server_application/app.h:11: undefined reference to `Poco::Util::ServerApplication::~ServerApplication()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE[_ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl::~IPv6SocketAddressImpl()':
/usr/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:118: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE[_ZTVN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE]+0x50): undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::toString[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o): in function `Poco::Net::Impl::IPv4SocketAddressImpl::~IPv4SocketAddressImpl()':
/usr/include/Poco/Net/SocketAddressImpl.h:56: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl::~SocketAddressImpl()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE[_ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv6SocketAddressImplE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE[_ZTIN4Poco3Net4Impl21IPv4SocketAddressImplE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::Impl::SocketAddressImpl'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTI11Application[_ZTI11Application]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Util::ServerApplication'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(app.cc.o):(.data.rel.local.DW.ref._ZTIN4YAML9ExceptionE[DW.ref._ZTIN4YAML9ExceptionE]+0x0): undefined reference to `typeinfo for YAML::Exception'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(handler_factory.cc.o): in function `RequestHandler::RequestHandler()':
/home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.h:9: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler::HTTPRequestHandler()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(handler_factory.cc.o): in function `HandlerFactory::~HandlerFactory()':
/home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler_factory/handler_factory.h:9: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory::~HTTPRequestHandlerFactory()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(handler_factory.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTI14HandlerFactory[_ZTI14HandlerFactory]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(request_handler.cc.o): in function `RequestHandler::handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest&, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse&)':
/home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:20: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::getContentLength() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:22: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPResponse::setStatus(Poco::Net::HTTPResponse::HTTPStatus)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:24: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::getContentLength() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:27: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST[abi:cxx11]'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:29: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::getContentLength() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:32: undefined reference to `tinyxml2::XMLDocument::XMLDocument(bool, tinyxml2::Whitespace)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:33: undefined reference to `tinyxml2::XMLDocument::Parse(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:36: undefined reference to `tinyxml2::XMLElement::GetText() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:32: undefined reference to `tinyxml2::XMLDocument::~XMLDocument()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.cc:32: undefined reference to `tinyxml2::XMLDocument::~XMLDocument()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(request_handler.cc.o): in function `RequestHandler::~RequestHandler()':
/home/sschiz/CLionProjects/auchan-handler-microservice/src/request_handler/request_handler.h:9: undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler::~HTTPRequestHandler()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/libsrc.a(request_handler.cc.o):(.data.rel.ro._ZTI14RequestHandler[_ZTI14RequestHandler]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/list_status_path_test.dir/build.make:100: tests/list_status_path_test] Ошибка 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:190: tests/CMakeFiles/list_status_path_test.dir/all] Ошибка 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all]
```

Comment: did you installed the `yaml-cpp` (build its `INSTALL` target)? If yes then you need `find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)`.

Comment: I’ve already wrote

Comment: See below: there is a poco error

Comment: how? explain plz

Comment: @dedicat4d, have you found any solution?